# Solving $\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{2xy}{x^2+y^2}$ using $\epsilon,\delta$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, epsilon-delta

So we have the following limit to solve, which I solved using multiple paths method (by taking $y=mx$) and investigating the resulting fucntion, and it turned out that limit doesnt exists.$$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{2xy}{x^2+y^2}$$

But I cannot prove/disprove the existence of limit using $\epsilon,\delta$ method. I tried following (by taking limit say $0$): $$\left|\frac{2xy}{x^2+y^2}-0\right|<\epsilon$$
$$\frac{2xy}{x^2+y^2}<\frac{2x}{y}<\epsilon$$
and $$x^2+y^2<\delta^2$$

Now I cannot relate between the two inequalities meaningfully to disporve the existence of the limit, so I require the assistance here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: By selecting $0$ as you have, you'll only be able to prove that the limit is not $0$ (if it exists). But even so, if you wish to show $0$ is not the limit, try considering $\varepsilon = 1/2$, and assume a $\delta$ exists by contradiction. What happens when you consider the point $(x, y) = (\delta/2, \delta/2)$?

Comment: @TheoBendit Can you pls show stepwise, I am pretty new to this calculus course

Comment: Try converting into polar coordinates.  f simplifies very nicely.  Then disproving the limit as r->0, remembering that $\theta$ can take on any value inside the  r circle.

Comment: @nickalh ik, but I specifically asked solution using $\epsilon, \delta $ method

Comment: it will still be the $\epsilon, \delta$ method, just in a transformed coordinate system.

Comment: The $~\epsilon, ~\delta~$ method is applicable to **polar coordinates** as well as cartesian coordinates.  As $~(x,y) \to (0,0),~$ $~(x,y)~$ is expressible as $~\left[r\cos(\theta), r\sin(\theta)\right],~$ where $~0 < r < \delta~$ and $~x^2 + y^2 = r^2.~$  Then, the critical issue is whether the limit changes, as $~\theta~$ changes.

Comment: One way to prove no limit exists, which is often convenient, is to show that the function is not Cauchy (in a generalized sense): that is, there is some $\varepsilon > 0$ such that for each $\delta > 0$, there exist $x, y$ with $0 < \lVert x \rVert < \delta, 0 < \lVert y \rVert < \delta$ and $\lVert f(x) - f(y) \rVert > \varepsilon$.  In this case, within any punctured disc of radius $\delta$, you can find points $(\delta/2, 0)$ at which the function has value 0, and $(\delta/2, \delta/2)$ at which the function has value 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us assume the function has a limit $L \in \Bbb{R}$ as $(x, y) \to (0, 0)$. We can use the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definition to obtain a contradiction.

How will this work? As per the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definition, we know that we can force the function value $f(x, y)$ to be come $\varepsilon$-close to our limit $L$ (and we get *total control* over what that $\varepsilon > 0$ is, but we'll choose it later), so long as as we take $(x, y)$ sufficiently close (i.e. closer than some $\delta$ that we have no control over) to $(0, 0)$. If we can pick $(x_0, y_0)$ that is within this $\delta$ from $0$ (again, we don't know what $\delta$ is, or have any control over it, but we do get to pick our $(x_0, y_0)$), then we are guaranteed that $|f(x_0, y_0) - L| < \varepsilon$.

Normally, we're interested in ensuring that our $f(x_0, y_0)$ is indeed within $\varepsilon$. Now, it's essentially an assumption. We *choose* our $(x_0, y_0)$ carefully, and the fact that $|f(x_0, y_0) - L| < \varepsilon$ means that we can figure out roughly where $L$ lies! Specifically, it means that
$$f(x_0, y_0) - \varepsilon < L < f(x_0, y_0) + \varepsilon$$
This is good: we don't know the limit, but we can narrow it down to a small interval. And because we have *some* control over the value of $f(x_0, y_0)$, and all the control over $\varepsilon$, we get some control over this interval.

To get our contradiction, we just need to narrow $f(x_0, y_0)$ down to being in two small intervals that don't intersect! Which intervals would they be?

You know from your own investigation that, by following different lines through the origin, you get different limits. You might have noticed that following $y = x$, i.e. taking function values of the form $f(x, x)$, that you constantly get $1$. Whereas, if you take $y = 0$, i.e. function values of the form $f(x, 0)$, you constantly get $0$.

If we follow the lines to within distance $\delta$ of $(0, 0)$ (no matter how small $\delta$ ends up being), then we guarantee that $L$ lies within distance $\varepsilon$ of $1$, but also distance $\varepsilon$ of $0$. But, of course, we get to choose $\varepsilon$! What if we made $\varepsilon = 1/2$? We cannot have $L$ be within half distance of $1$ and half distance of $0$. Otherwise, we would have
$$-\frac{1}{2} < L < \frac{1}{2} < L < \frac{3}{2},$$
which would imply $L < L$, a contradiction. Choosing $\varepsilon$ to be half the difference between $1$ and $0$ ensured that our two little intervals, one around $0$, the other around $1$, do not intersect, which gives us our contradiction.

Let's prove it properly:

**Proof**

Assume $\lim_{(x, y) \to (0, 0)} \frac{2xy}{x^2 + y^2} = L$. Let $\varepsilon = \frac{1}{2}$. By the limit definition, there exists some $\delta > 0$ such that
\begin{align*}
0 < \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} < \delta &\implies |f(x, y) - L| < \varepsilon = \frac{1}{2} \\
&\implies f(x, y) - \frac{1}{2} < L < f(x, y) + \frac{1}{2}.
\end{align*}
Consider $(x_0, y_0) = (\delta/2, 0)$. [This is a "close enough" point along the line $y = 0$.] Note that $f(x_0, y_0) = 0$. Then,
$$0 < \sqrt{x_0^2 + y_0^2} = \sqrt{\frac{\delta^2}{4} + 0} = \frac{\delta}{2} < \delta.$$
By the limit definition, we conclude that
$$f(x_0, y_0) - \frac{1}{2} < L < f(x_0, y_0) + \frac{1}{2},$$
that is
$$-\frac{1}{2} < L < \frac{1}{2}.$$
Similarly, consider now $(x_1, y_1) = (\delta/2, \delta/2)$. [This is a "close enough" point along the line $y = x$.] Note that $f(x_1, y_1) = 1$. Once again, we get
$$0 < \sqrt{x_1^2 + y_1^2} = \sqrt{\frac{\delta^2}{4} + \frac{\delta^2}{4}} = \sqrt{\frac{\delta^2}{2}} = \frac{\delta}{\sqrt{2}} < \delta.$$
Thus, by the limit definition,
$$f(x_1, y_1) - \frac{1}{2} < L < f(x_1, y_1) + \frac{1}{2}$$
i.e.
$$1 - \frac{1}{2} < L < 1 + \frac{1}{2} \iff \frac{1}{2} < L < \frac{3}{2}.$$
But, this is a contradiction. We could previously conclude that $L < \frac{1}{2}$, but we have now just concluded $L > \frac{1}{2}$. Thus, our assumption that the limit existed must be false. $\square$